# Pig Java UDF Parsing String based on positions, return bag containing substrings with a generated key

Tags: java, apache-pig, udf

I have a column that is a String field.  I need to read in this String, stored it in a bag and also give it a key (so when I stored it as JSON its unique.

My example data file is:
         **"test, kyle"**

I want my output to looked like: 
               **{"test":[{"key": "test"}, {"value":"kyle"}]}**

```
public class BagTupleExampleUDF extends EvalFunc<DataBag> {

TupleFactory mTupleFactory = TupleFactory.getInstance();
BagFactory mBagFactory = BagFactory.getInstance();
int counter = 0;
static String fieldNames[] = {"key", "value"};


@Override
public DataBag exec(Tuple tuple) throws IOException {
    // expect one string
    if (tuple == null || tuple.size() == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("BagTupleExampleUDF: requires input parameters.");
    }
    try {

        String key = (String) tuple.get(0);
        String input = (String) tuple.get(1);

        DataBag output = mBagFactory.newDefaultBag();

            output.add(mTupleFactory.newTuple(Collections.singletonList(key)));
            output.add(mTupleFactory.newTuple(Collections.singletonList(input)));


        return output;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IOException("BagTupleExampleUDF: caught exception processing input.", e);
    }
}

public Schema outputSchema(Schema input) {
    // Function returns a bag with this schema: { (Double), (Double) }
    // Thus the outputSchema type should be a Bag containing a Double
    try{

        Schema bagSchema = new Schema();
        String schemaName =  getSchemaName(this.getClass().getName().toLowerCase(), input);

        bagSchema.add(new Schema.FieldSchema(fieldNames[counter], DataType.CHARARRAY));
        counter++;
        return new Schema(new Schema.FieldSchema(schemaName, bagSchema, DataType.BAG));
        }
    catch (Exception e){
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

The problem i'm having is this line:

```
bagSchema.add(new Schema.FieldSchema(fieldNames[counter], DataType.CHARARRAY));
```

Basically each value I read in from my tuple needs a different indentifying key, so that when this finishes with Pig I can refer to these new columns that I've added.

I'm still very new to Pig and especially UDFS so let me know if more information is needed.